# Redshift POSIX regex order does not matter

Tags: regex, posix, amazon-redshift

I'm querying data from AWS Redshift by using the POSIX regular expressions. However, I have difficulties to find the whole string by finding multiple words without considering the order.

The table is like this:

```
ID  | full_term 
123 | juice apple farm
123 | apple juice original
123 | banana juice
```

For example, I'm looking for a whole string that contains both `apple` and `juice`, so I expect to get the first two rows. My current query:

```
SELECT full_term FROM data_table
WHERE full_term ~ '(.*apple+)(.*juice+).*$'
```

However, the order does matter in this method. I also tried `full_term ~ '(?=.*apple+)(?=.*juice+).*$'` but I got an error message `[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Invalid preceding regular expression prior to repetition operator.  The error occurred while parsing the regular expression fragment: '(?>>>HERE>>>=.*apple+)'.` I just realized `?=` does not work in Redshift.

Is using the UDF the only solution in this case?
Also, I only want exact `apple` and `juice` in full terms. That is to say, `pineapple` should not be included.

Comment: Probably you may use `WHERE full_term ~ 'apple.*juice|juice.*apple'`. Also, you may use two `STRPOS` calls with `AND` to see if both words appear in a record.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Thanks a lot! It worked like magic! What I did is `SELECT full_term FROM data_table WHERE full_term ~ 'apple.*juice|juice.*apple' AND strpos(full_term , 'apple')>=0 AND strpos(full_term , 'juice')>=0` A quick follow up, if I do not want `pineapple` shows in the results, how can I do that?

Comment: Ok, that means you cannot rely on `STRPOS`. I do not know if this regex engine allows word boundaries. What word boundaries do you want to match? Words between whitespaces? Or between non-letters? Or non-word chars (that is, not a letter, digit or `_`)?

Comment: Please try `WHERE full_term ~ '(^|[^A-Za-z])(apple.*juice|juice.*apple)($|[^A-Za-z])'`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew I think word boundaries `\b` does not work on Redshift.

Comment: Ok, what about `WHERE full_term ~ '(^|[^A-Za-z])(apple.*juice|juice.*apple)($|[^A-Za-z])'`?

Comment: It would still include other words containing apple. All in all, I eventually created my UDF that using python `re` to do dynamic matching. Thank you so much for your advice!

Comment: Not sure what you mean now. I thought you needed a boolean result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably most clearly written as `AND`ed separate regular expression matches. To ensure that you don't match e.g. `pineapple` when looking for `apple`, you need to check that on either side of the search term is either a space character or the beginning/end of the line:

```
SELECT full_term FROM data_table
WHERE full_term ~ '(^|\\s)apple(\\s|$)'
  AND full_term ~ '(^|\\s)juice(\\s|$)'
```